# DebugTrace in Microsoft driver examples

Tags: c, debugging, driver, wdk

Hi I was wondering if anyone knows what the function Debugtrace does in the driver examples given with WDDK. I could not find the function online nor in the source code, thanks.

```
   DebugTrace( DEBUG_TRACE_ALL_IO,
                ("[Ctx]: CtxPreCreate -> Enter (Cbd = %p, FileObject = %p)\n",
                 Cbd,
                 FltObjects->FileObject) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a `#define` in source files. Its little wrapper over `DbgPrint` that prints message in debugger window.

In some of sample source files I find:

```
#define DebugTrace(Level, Data)               \
    if ((Level) & Globals.DebugLevel) {       \
         Data                                 \
    }
```